# Scattering images across photoshop canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, photoshop-scripting

I've tried to find a respective answer for my problem but wasn't able to find any help so asking a question here. I have around 100 JPEG/PNG files which I'd like to scatter across a photoshop canvas of around 43200x30300 pixels. I tried to find pattern makers online, most of them only support SVG files. The final desired result is like this:

[image: The final desired result should be like this]

Also, I'd appreciate if you can let me know if there's a possibility of rotating images randomly too.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Technically it's possible, however you need to figure out the algorithm first. On your example images are put in a specific way: it looks like they are bin-packed with additions of some images being put on intersections of some other images. _That_ will be a difficult part, not the script itself

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I guess we can just focus on one thing for now. Lets say we don't want any intersection and we just put images one after another, would that be easier to program in a script?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If the final result is to be similar to the image you posted, then these images have not been scattered "randomly".  Many of them seem to be aligned to a grid. Photoshop has a Contact Sheet II script which can be used. There's [a tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0oPMeYzEW0). This could be used as a starting point, perhaps with a few images manually placed to make everything look a bit more random.

Comment: Yes, this's easy, especially if your images have the same size: it's a matter or creating several loops for rows and columns. Here's [a good place to start](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) with scripting

Comment: Maybe a script or a collage app of some kind would be easier, but I'm thinking I'd try Indesign. You can place multiple images in a grid very easily in Indesign... Maybe that could be the more uniform background and then you could place a more random collection of images on top of that. You can import multiple images, which will basically wait for you to place them one by one by clicking or clicking and dragging to place them at a specific size. This could be your second pass of images placed more randomly on top.